# Excel VBA: Loop IF statement through two columns

Tags: vba, loops, date, range

I have a client list with various information. Column C shows inception date, Column Q shows Status.

I need to loop an IF statement through Column C that checks todays date() and if the clients corresponding status is 100%. Then adds 1 year to the date in column C if true.

```
Private Sub Workbook_Open()
    Dim ID As Date
    Dim Status As Long

    ID = Sheets("Kunder").Range("C" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row


    If ID>= Date And Status = 1 Then
    ID.Value = ID.Value + 365
    End If


    End Sub
```

Thank you very much :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Date in excel is just number. So,

```
Dim ID as Double
```

To loop through all cell in column C

```
Dim cl As Range

With Sheets("Kunder")
    For Each cl In Intersect(.Range("C:C"), .UsedRange)
        If cl.Value = ID And cl.Offset(, 14).Value = 1 Then
             cl.Value = cl.Value + 365
        End If
    Next cl
End With
```

But, remember about leap years, they have 366 days. 
 cl.Offset(, 14) is Q column, remember about it when inserting/deleting columns.

Comment: Thank you! I guess "ID=date" was missing, but now it works like a charm. Good day to you sir.

Comment: In terms of the Leap year do you think adding 365,25 days would work?

Comment: I don't think so. I mean, this code will work good in 2017, but if you need it working in 2019 you shall update the macro. If you think that you will not remember about this or you will leave your work earlier, you can add variable that is 366 in leap and 365 in normal year. Just for the record.

Answer (score 0):

This is a basic loop with condition, looping through two columns - column `A` and column `B`. Try it step by step on an empty Excel file and you will easily adjust yours to it:

```
Public Sub BasicLoop()

    Dim i As Long

    For i = 1 To 100
        ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 1) = i * 2
        If i * 2 / 4 Mod 2 = 0 Then
            ActiveSheet.Cells(i, 2) = i * 4
        End If
    Next i

End Sub
```